# Check if Internet is Offline

Tags: vbscript

I am successfully retrieving webdata using

```
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") 
o.open "GET", "http://www.example.com/get.php", False 
o.send
```

However, if Internet is OFF (no connection), the vbs file gives error.
So how can I make if statement, which checks if the internet is not online, don't try retrieve the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of checking whether there is an internet connection, you could handle errors like this:

```
On Error Resume Next 'swallow errors
o.open "GET", "http://www.example.com/get.php", False 
o.send 
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "An error occured. Data not retrieved."
    'or whatever else you want to do in such a case.
End If
On Error Goto 0 'back to normal error behaviour
```

This has the advantage of being able to deal with other errors besides just not having a connection, e.g. example.com website is down, etc.

Comment: It should suffice to enable error handling after `o.open ...`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Well, actually, the error occurs on `o.send`! I just yanked out my internet cable to test this.

Comment: Exactly. Enable error handling after `o.open ...`, before `o.send`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Ah, right, gotcha. I misread your comment the first time around.